# What is the difference of two build.gradles in project root directory and in app folder?

Tags: android, android-studio, build.gradle

I just noticed there are two build.gradle files in my project. Is it because I used gradle wrapper while importing the project?

In Android Studio what is the difference between build.gradle in project root directory and build.gradle in app folder?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "app" folder is just one module. When writing more complex apps you may have multiple modules. The `build.gradle` at the module level relates only to that module whereas the `build.gradle` at the root relates to all modules in the project.

Example from project level `build.gradle`:

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}
```

This is saying all modules should use `jcenter` repository for resolving dependencies. Now a potentially confusing thing is a terminology clash between gradle and android studio. An android studio "module" is a gradle "project" hence "allprojects".

Comment: so the build.gradle in root directory can have lower and higher version of build_tool_classpath compared to build.gradle inside app of each modules?

Comment: Do you mean this line: `classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.3.0` ?

Comment: Yes you can override it at the module level. But I've never wanted/needed to myself.

Comment: Thank you that a gave a lot of insights to build.gradle

Comment: So by default the two files complement each other, but you can override things by re-specifying them, yes.